# Differentiate past events from future events (past and future, both will have different color)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plugins, calendar

Im using the event calendar plugin from this website http://www.vissit.com/jquery-event-calendar-plugin-english-version/

[image: The event calendar is able to display all of events with the event coloured as green as shown in image.]

Currently, the event calendar is able to display all of events with the event coloured as green e.g. 1/5/2016, 3/5/2016 and etc. as shown in image. However, the event calendar I want is for example, today is 5/2/2016, if referring the image above, the past event will be 1/5/2016. I want the past event to have different color from future event(coloured in green) to show the difference between past and future event. Note if there is a event in 5/2/2016(today date), it will still consider as future event.

This is the code that determine today date (as shown below)

```
    for (dayCount = 1; dayCount <= daysOnTheMonth; dayCount++) {
        var dayClass = "";

        if (day > 0 && dayCount === day && year === currentYear) {
            dayClass = "today";
        }

        daysList.push('<li id="dayList_' + dayCount + '" rel="'+dayCount+'" class="eventCalendar-day '+dayClass+'"><a href="#">' + dayCount + '</a></li>');
    }
```

The code that apply color to the days with events (as shown below)

```
// add mark in the dayList to the days with events
                if (eventYear == flags.wrap.attr('data-current-year') && eventMonth == flags.wrap.attr('data-current-month')) {
                    flags.wrap.find('.eventCalendar-currentMonth .eventCalendar-daysList #dayList_' + parseInt(eventDay)).addClass('eventCalendar-dayWithEvents');
                }
```

All of the code above is obtained from jquery.eventCalendar.js

Your kind help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There's probably a data-day attribute in the HTML, Kindly post a relevant section of it

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="eventCalendar" style="width:300px; margin: 50px auto;"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- plugin has dependency of moment.js to show dates -->
<script src="js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.eventCalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
/*
var data = [{ "date": "2016-04-29 00:00:00", "type": "meeting", "title": "Testing", "description": "Please work", "url": "" },
            { "date": "2016-04-30 00:00:00", "type": "demo", "title": "Project B demo", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url": "http://www.event2.com/" }

];
*/
$('#eventCalendar').eventCalendar({
    //jsonData:data,
    eventsjson:'data.json',
    jsonDateFormat:'human',
    dateFormat: 'dddd D-MM-YYYY'
    });


});
</script>
```